# Can RSS GUIDs contain hashes?

Tags: rss, guid

Is it OK to use the hash character in the GUID field in an RSS field, and if so are `thing#1` and `thing#2` considered to be separate GUIDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Aggregators must view the guid as a string. There are no rules for the syntax. It's up to the creator of the RSS document, to establish the uniqueness of the string." Source: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_guid.asp)

Answer (score 3):

From the [RSS 2.0 Spec, <guid> sub-element of <item>](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#ltguidgtSubelementOfLtitemgt):

> There are no rules for the syntax of a guid. Aggregators must view them as a string. It's up to the source of the feed to establish the uniqueness of the string.